# How to pass profile while running mvn test for a springboot application

Tags: spring-boot, maven

I am trying to run test cases of spring boot application.
For that I tried using `mvn test -Dspring.profiles.active=test`.
But it did not work.
Do I need to add profile in `pom.xml`

Could you please help.

Answer (score 3):

The java arguments come before the maven lifecycle parameter:

```
mvn -Dspring.profiles.active=test test
```

You can also add `<argLine>` property to maven surefire plugin to apply to all tests.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <systemPropertyVariables>
      <testEnvironment>true</testEnvironment>
    </systemPropertyVariables>
    <argLine>-Dspring.profiles.active=test</argLine>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to run a test with a profile is using the `ActiveProfiles` annotation (assuming JUnit 5):

```
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class MyApplicationTest {

  @Test
  void test() {
    // implement actual test here
  }
}
```

This will start your Spring Application with the `test` profile active.

Comment: There isn't anything here specifically for JUnit 5. It works with other testing libraries as well.

Comment: Well, if you use JUnit 4, you need to add `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` at the class level. And the class and method should be public.

Comment: Ah. I meant specifically using the `@ActiveProfiles` annotation. It works with any testing framework.